# No Symbols found for architecture. Xcode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have having an issue when I add new classes to an Xcode Solution, I cannot compile it.

I take the same class and add it to a new project and it works just fine.

This is what i am getting.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RIButtonItem", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MenuViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

All I did was add the following classes to my project.  https://github.com/gfontenot/UIAlertView-Blocks

It all started to happen when I upgraded to the latest version of Xcode (4.3.1)  I have since downgraded but I still have this issue.  I am not missing any libraries like the other solutions state, which I why I am posting this.

Comment: Could your existing solution be a Mac solution by mistake perhaps?

Comment: Make sure to activate Target Membership for your classes.

Comment: No, it is an iOS Solution, I have been working on it for a month now and for some stupid reason I thought it would be  a good idea to up XCode to 4.3.1.  Now whenever I add a new class like this, I end up with this issue.

Comment: Have you ensured that the newly added class actually made it into the "Compile Sources" build phase?

Comment: @MattWilding That was it!  When I speak of you, I will speak well.  So simple, yet I totally missed it!  Thank you to everyone for your help!

Comment: Good, I'll upgrade that comment to an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, linker errors like that are usually the result of a source file being omitted from the "Compile Sources" build phase, usually after failing to check the "Add to Targets" button when dragging the source files into the project from another location. The headers will be found, allowing the source to compile, but since the object files were never generated, the linker will fail.

Comment: Thank you! I was also running into this issue with the new Xcode 4.3 build.